How to use function pointer for a macro function
why it is not working when I use function pointer for macro function as below?
int func(int a, int b)
{
    return a*b;
}

#define multiple1(num) func(1u, num)
#define multiple2(num) func(2u, num)

typedef int (*func_multiple) (int a);

int main() {
    int result;
    func_multiple func_array[] = {multiple1, multiple2};

    result = (*func_array[1])(5);
    printf("result = %d", result);

    return 0;
}

error: 'multiple1' undeclared (first use in this function)
error: 'multiple2' undeclared (first use in this function)
I want to know what is wrong here?
